# Assign address to pointer argument, in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, arguments, memory-address

I have a struct, say:

```
 struct Astruct {
   int a;
   int b;
 }
```

And I have av instance of that struct say:

```
private:
  Astruct My_List;
```

Then I have a function that I want to get the address of My_List.

```
public:
  void Get_My_List(Astruct* List) {

    List = &My_List;

  }
```

However it seems to always set the argument Astruct* List = 0;
I know I probably could make a function called Astruct& Get_Address() or something but in this particular case I would like to know why I can't assign addresses in the argument. I mean it is possible to pass arguments as references and change the data. Or maybe I start to understand the problem now when I write this... Anyway just to be sure, is it possible to change the address the pointer points to via an argument? Or can I just change the data the pointer points to?

Comment: `List` is a local variable. Changes to it aren't visible to the outside.

Comment: The code above cannot set `Astruct* List` to `0` since `&` never returns `0`. The rest of your question shows you are seriously confused about pointers. So something is going on that is not reflected in the code you have posted. Please post a **complete** program that illustrates your confusion. The program only needs to be a few lines long.

Comment: tkausl is probably right, you think that changing `List` should be visible outside the `Get_My_List` function but C++ never works like that. Any changes to what `List` points at will be visible outside the function, but changes to `List` **itself** will not.

Comment: Seems this is the usual newbie confusion about pointers, failing to understand that the pointer and what it points at are different things, and different rules apply.

Comment: I figured it out. Yes it was about confusion, but not pointer confusion, more like argument confusion!

Comment: Is it possible to mark a comment as an answer? Because tkausl's comment actually answers the question. I first thought he meant that "My_List" was local but then I re-read the comment. It was early in the morning...

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Yes it was about confusion, but not pointer confusion, more like argument confusion!
So the problem is that I thought I could "return" values via arguments. I thought that because I have previously created functions that takes a pointer and then the function changes the data the address points to. And yes it is "set" to zero. I mean @john is right, the code can't set it, but it is never changed. Because the value I pass in is initialized to zero and I can't change an argument, in this case Astruct* List. So the pointer I pass remains unchanged.
So what I had to do was to make the function take a pointer to a pointer.

```
void Get_My_List(Astruct** List) {
  *List = &My_List;
}
```

And pass the address to the pointer instead. In that case I can change the data the pointer points to, which is a pointer.

Thanks, bye!

Comment: Your explanation is right, but you should rather pass a reference to the pointer (unless `nullptr` is a valid input, which it isnt)

Comment: @idclev463035818 I consider that personal preference. It *is* useful to be able to see that the function changes its argument because `&` is written before the argument.

Comment: @user253751 I disagree. Passing a nullptr to that function will cause UB. Using a reference instead of pointer achieves the same but is objectively more safe

Comment: @idclev463035818 One ground rule of using pointers is that null pointers are UB unless otherwise specified. So don't do that.

Comment: @user253751 that ground rule is personal preference, if you take that away then using a reference is safer. Nevermind, lets agree to disagree

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the reference-to-pointer:

```
void Get_My_List(Astruct*& List) {
    List = &My_List;
}
```

and call it like that:

```
AstructHolder obj{};
Astruct* my_ptr{nullptr};
obj.Get_My_List(my_ptr);
```